# C++ 2D vector of characters from cin

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I would like a Square 2D array that I can access by indexes. Here is my code:

```
vector<vector<char>> B;
int SIZE;
cin >> SIZE;

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            cin >> B[i][j];
    }
```

Inputs are are in the form:

```
3
oox
oxo
xoo
```

So it want a grid of SIZE x Size of arbitrary characters. The characters are not separated by spaces.

However even when I try separating by spaces my code fails after the first character input.

I've also tried using push_back(). But I want to be able to access the elements.

For example B[0][2] should give me 'x'. How can I do this?

Comment: Side note: Many (maybe even most) C++ programmers will associate ALL_UPPERCASE_IDENTIFIERS with `#define` macros and constants. Name your variables accordingly because the more you surprise people, the more bug reports you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

The error in the code is that you didn't allocate memory to the 2D Vector and directly started using.

```
vector<vector<char>> B;   //HERE YOU DECLARE 2D Vector 
int SIZE;
cin >> SIZE;

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
            cin >> B[i][j];   // BUT NO MEMORY ALLOCATED
    }
```

Instead, use the following method:

```
int SIZE;
cin >> SIZE;
vector<vector<char>> B(SIZE,vector<char>(SIZE)); // Here we allocate the memory
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
  for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++){
    cin >> B[i][j];
  }
}
```

The Memory allocation step is

```
vector<vector<char>> B(SIZE,vector<char>(SIZE));
```

Here we create a vector of size "**SIZE**" which whose each element contains another vector of size "**SIZE**".

Also, you should provide input with space-separated characters:

```
3
o o x
o x o
x o o
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without specifying the size? I would like to make B a global variable and don't know size until I take input.

Comment: @musicalears global variables are evil and should be avoided. If you pass a variable around as a parameter, you have an easily auditable chain of who could have modified the contents. With a global variable, all functions are suspect as they all could have side effects. Not much of a issue with a small program, but   an unforced error when the programs get more complicated.

Comment: That said, define `vector<vector<char>> B;` as you are now. Then later  `B= vector<vector<char>>(SIZE,vector<char>(SIZE));` to assign a band-new `vector` of `vector`s over top of what's currently in `B`.